# Continuous Integration workflow using Github, Travis CI, and Nodejitsu

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, webhooks, nodejitsu

I am trying to create the following workflow for continuous integration on my project

- Developer commits code change to Github
- Github sends entire codebase to Travis CI
- Travis CI does the following

  - Runs tests
  - Builds distribution worthy package, saves in filesystem location local to Travis CI
  - Deploys distribution worthy package to Nodejitsu
- Nodejitsu restarts server with the distribution worthy package

Is this possible? What are the steps? Via Github webhooks, I do have Travis CI running tests, and Nodejitsu deploying (untested and distribution worthy) Github codebase, but I do not have the workflow described above. Am I expecting something that is not possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and how we deploy many of our systems internally.

For a quick getting started guide please try:

- https://www.nodejitsu.com/getting-started-with-github

Detailed documentation can be found here:

- https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/features/webhooks/

If you have any other questions, feel free to reach out to Nodejitsu support.

Comment: I am not giving Nodejitsu, a company whose product that I'm merely trialing, my Github password. I don't think that I'd give any 3rd party my Github password.

Comment: we don't store passwords, it is only used to generate a token

Comment: Anyhow, my repo is public. These instructions seem scattered, attempting to provide steps to multiple workflows, and assuming that I know which steps that I should ignore.

Comment: Scattered: the page is https://www.nodejitsu.com/getting-started-with-github/ "Getting started with Github" and the first step asks for my Github username/password, and then the second step says "If you already use Github, then..." Obviously I already use Github, or I wouldn't be on this page. It's just scattered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added it to our internal tracking system for the docs.

Comment: No problem. Is it possible to do what I'm looking to do? I'm comfortable storing my Travis CI and Nodejitsu usernames and passwords on Github, but not vice versa. Github is a known entity, Travis CI and Nodejitsu are up and comers. Not yet worthy of providing my Github username/password. I doubt that I'm alone.

Comment: Unintuitively, if I do this $ curl -X PUT -u nodejitsu-username api.nodejitsu.com/users/nodejitsu-username/tokens/github, and use the 'github' value for my Github/Nodejitsu password, then Nodejitsu does seem to keep the package in 'archived' state (for a few moments). I guess this is a step in the right direction.